# How to check value of randomly generated sprite in Andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine, game-engine

My code goes something like this:

```
while(x<30)
 {
  int randomvalue= generaterandomnumber();
  Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(location[coordx], location[coordy], spritetobegenerated[randomvalue-1].deepCopy(),getVertexBufferObjectManager())
  (Touchevents)
  x++;
  }
```

The sprites are saved in an array of sprites named spritetobegenerated[].

Since the code generates these sprites randomly, I need some way to know which sprite is involved when a touch event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I. You need to override onAreaTouched function in every sprite, this way:

ex.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SPRITE_COUNT; i++) {
    float x = (float) (Math.random() * CAMERA_WIDTH);
    float y = (float) (Math.random() * CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    final Sprite face = new Sprite(x, y this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            this.setX(this.getX() + 1);
            return true;
        }
    };
    scene.attachChild(face);
    scene.registerTouchArea(face);
}
scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

II. I would extend an own Sprite class, ex.: MySprite, where I override onAreaTouched function globally and I would introduce an index too. After that I would put a switch (or if) statement into onAreaTouched depends on the sprite index.

Comment: For I. : Since the sprites are being created in a loop, How does @Override affect it?

Comment: Every sprite has an own onAreaTouched function, which you override

(I mentioned index earlier: it is not sure that it is necessary.)